# Invoke-Command not reaching catch block

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline, invoke-command

I am trying to run a trace on remote machine and am expecting to get an error that file cannot be found as it isn't created but this is what I want and then code should reach `catch` block. I am using this with a Jenkins pipeline and it should return 1 with error exit but it is returning green.

I have tried setting `$ErrorActionPreference` to "Stop" and added `-ErrorAction Stop` to end of command but still passing.

```
$Server = $args[2]
$username = $args[3]
$password = $args[4]

$pass = "$password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("ad\$username", $pass)

try {
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Cred

    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        netsh trace start capture=yes tracefile=C:\Traces1\netsh.etl
    } -ErrorAction Stop
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $Time
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        netsh trace stop
    }
} catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host $ErrorMessage
    exit 1
}

exit 0
```

Comment: [Also related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42175577/1630171).

Comment: i cannot get `netsh` to error out if the file is not there ... it simply creates the file. so ... how are you triggering an error?

Comment: It cannot find the folder to create it but this is what I want.

Comment: Powershell doesn't inherently error on failed commands like it does with cmdlets or .NET members. You have to check `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` to gauge success of an external program like `netsh`, `ping`, etc.